# Correct notation to illustrate the product of a weighted path

Tags: notation

I am struggling to represent a situation using the correct mathematical notation. I have a graph that consists of a series of nodes (1-4) and edges which represent movement pathways between nodes. The edges have an attribute *d*, which represents the distance between the two adjacent nodes.

[an example of a network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSyw6.png)

The probability of successfully moving between two adjacent nodes *i* and *j* is a function of distance (*d*):

$$P_{success} = e^{-d_{i,j}/10}$$

e.g. for each adjacent pair of nodes in the figure above the probability of success would be:

$$P_{success, 1,2} = e^{-0.5/10} = 0.95$$

$$P_{success, 2,3} = e^{-0.1/10} = 0.9$$

$$P_{success, 3,4} = e^{-1.5/10} = 0.86$$

Now I apply an additional toll to the probability of success ($P_{toll}$) which can range from 0 to 1. If $P_{toll}$ = 0.5 then the probability of moving from node 1 to node 4 would be:

$$(0.95 * 0.5) * (0.9 * 0.5) * (0.86 * 0.5) = 0.09$$

**My Question:**

How do I present a general form of the above situation mathematically?

This is my attempt (which I know is wrong), hopefully I am at least on the right track…

$$\prod^j_{i:j}(e^{-d_{i,j}/10}  P_{toll})$$

**Edit**

To clarify, I am not only interested in the distance from node 1 to 4, but from any node to any other node.

Comment: $$\prod_{i=\mathrm{start}}^{\mathrm{finish}}$$ Look at your values, what is the first $i$? the last $i$? Notice how $j$ is always $i+1$? Lastly, it's ambiguous to me if the $P_\mathrm{toll}$ is currently written inside the product, or multiplied after the product. It should either be inside, noted by parentheses, or it needs raised to the appropriate power.

Comment: @Joe thanks for the response. Ok, I think I want $p_{toll}$ inside the product, so I can do that with parentheses. regarding i and j I am not only interested in the distance from node 1 to 4, but from any node to any other node. So I'm not sure how that would look.

Comment: You would use one variable for the start, one variable for the finish, and a dummy variable for the index.